# percentage summary per hour for 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm trying to get an up time percentage for a 24 hour period broken down per hour.

If the column AlertID is 1, then the system is up. If AlertID is anything other number then it's considered down.

Here is what I have that currently isn't working and has a bad performance result but let's just make it work first. The UpTime column is always 0.

```
 SELECT a.dayhour,
       ( (SELECT Count(*)
          FROM   commandhistory
          WHERE  commandid = '4263745C-5603-4E3D-AFB2-CA0E27969D0B'
                 AND alertid = 1
                 AND Datepart(hour, recordeddttm) = a.dayhour * 100) / (SELECT
         Count(*) FROM commandhistory
         WHERE commandid = '4263745C-5603-4E3D-AFB2-CA0E27969D0B'
           AND Datepart(hour, recordeddttm) = a.dayhour) ) AS UpTime
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS DayHour UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23) a
       LEFT JOIN commandhistory h
              ON a.dayhour = Datepart(hour, recordeddttm)
GROUP  BY a.dayhour
ORDER  BY a.dayhour
```

Example Table: (there is other data but i don't care about it for this instance)

```
uniqueidentifier CommandID
smallint         AlertID
datetime         RecordedDTTM
```

AlertID can be 1-5. 1 means it's up, any other number should be treated as down.

Comment: Not sure why someone flagged this as closed. Did I miss something?

Comment: It's a move vote to dba.stackexchange.com, so not really a close vote. The performance tuning experts live there, so in that way it makes sense.

Comment: Schema and sample data would make this far easier to fix.

Comment: so alert ID = 1 means it's up and 0 means it's down? can you provide some sample data?

Comment: If it isn't working, current performance is irrelevant.. Can you explain how it isn't working?

Comment: Ok, now that you have clarified the alertID, are these inserted every minute... or will a new record only be inserted when the status changes? i ask because you use count() which is odd for this case

Comment: @scsimon records are inserted no matter the status.

Comment: like ever X minutes or seconds or... at random or...? Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: @scsimon it's random. I can get sample data soon as I'm back.

Comment: It's possible this query works but you need to cast your COUNT(*) because it is an integer.  and int/int = int which will either be 0 or 1 in this case. Any way, I provided what I think is what you are looking for below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT Datepart(hour, recordeddttm) as DayHour
    , sum(case when alertID=1 then 1 else 0 end) as UpTimeCt
    , sum(case when alertID <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DownTimeCt
    , Count(*) AllCt
FROM   commandhistory
WHERE  commandid = '4263745C-5603-4E3D-AFB2-CA0E27969D0B'
--AND cast(recordeddttm as date) = [some date] --This is optional but limits data set
group by Datepart(hour, recordeddttm)
)

select DayHour
   , UpTimeCt
   , UpTimeRate = UpTimeCt/AllCt --AllCt might need to be cast
   , DownTimeCt
   , DownTimeRate = DownTimeCt / AllCt --AllCt might need to be cast
from cte
```